# Dojo Image Indicator while partial refresh not working in Notes 9

Tags: dojo, xpages

I am helping a co-worker with a issue in a production datatbase.  The database makes use of a visual indicator to show the user during long partial refreshes.  We are in the process of upgrading the application to Notes 9.0.1.

The method that is used is described in detail in this blog post by Eric Tomenga: https://www.socialbizug.org/blogs/tomenga/entry/dojo_loading_image_indicator_while_partial_refresh_loads_data?lang=en_us  (blog that Eric's references appears to be offline)

The code is not altered from what is shown in the post.  Works in 8.5.3 completely, but in 9.0.1, the "Please Wait" works but the spining image is absent.

My suspicion is that newer dojo version that Notes 9 uses changes something that breaks this.  Downgrading dojo versions is not an option.  Hoping for a workaround.

---

```
<xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onComplete>
<xp:this.onError><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onError>
```

This is added to the element you want to use it with (button in this case).  The following dojo modules are added to XPage resources: extlib.dijit.ExtLib + extlib.dijit.Loading

Comment: Can you post some code, Steve? Yes, Domino 9 uses Dojo 1.8 which can break some Dojo 1.6 code.

Comment: Tittle does not match the question - it works, just image is broken. Use your own image then, as suggested by @SteveZavocki.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to add the relevant Dojo module as well. You can see a working example of the code on the Admin page of the XPages Extension Library demo database. I can't remember off-hand which dojo module it is, so please post here if that solves it.

Comment: We just decided to ditch this method and go with this:  http://www.fdehedin.ch/183/displaying-fancy-loading-indicator-while-loading-ajax

Comment: My preferred option is Fredrik Norling's Standby Dialog Control on OpenNTF http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control. That answers my query on the Dojo module. Adding dojox.widget.Standby to your original code should solve it.

Comment: I am thinking that Dojo 1.8 breaks this method, but can't say for sure.  Whether it is best to leave question open, answer myself, or remove question I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I really like Fredrik's standby control and have used it myself.  In this case, I am helping co-worker and it is his call.